# How to swap specific bits between two bytes based on bit map?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

```
    For example: 
      If A -> 00001010(10), B-> 01000001(65), C -> 00011010(26)(Bit Map)
      So after swapping specific bits, New A(A') -> 00000000 and 
      New B(B') -> 01001011
  
    Explanation:
      A ->  00001010
      C ->  00011010(Swap bits b/w A and B if C's specific bit is 1,
                     I.e bit 4, 5, 7(direction from left to right)
      B ->  01000001
    ----------------
      A' -> 00000000
      B' -> 01001011
```

Comment: Is it a question?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, This is my first question to be posted. I am still not aware of the formatting style, Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Comment: while the formatting could be better, the problem is that I can't see the question. This question needs a little text to explain what you are doing and what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback @EasterBunnyBugSmasher . I will definitely incorporate the suggestions by you in all my future questions to be asked, This question was asked in an interview, So I wanted to find out the best and efficient way to solve this, Hence, didn't explained this in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple. To set `A` from `B` only bits `MASK`:

1. Clear all bits `MASK` from `A`: `D = A & ~MASK`
2. Get only bits `MASK` from `B`: `E = B & MASK`
3. Set required bits to `A`: `RES = D | E`

In most of languages it could look like this:

```
final int a = 0b00001010;
final int b = 0b01000001;
final int c = 0b00011010;

int aa = (a & ~c) | (b & c);
int bb = (b & ~c) | (a & c);

System.out.format("a: %08d\n", new BigInteger(Integer.toBinaryString(aa)));
System.out.format("a: %08d\n", new BigInteger(Integer.toBinaryString(bb)));
```

***P.S.** This is only basic bit operations.*

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I will try different cases and see if this fits.